# How to set a custom price of a product when adding to cart using an observer in Magento 2?

Tags: event-observer, price, magento-2.1.9

I want to set a custom price of the product when adding to cart using an observer.
For that, I added this code but it's not working

[image]

> app\code\Webkul\Hello\Observer\CustomPrice.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * Webkul Hello CustomPrice Observer
     *
     * @category    Webkul
     * @package     Webkul_Hello
     * @author      Webkul Software Private Limited
     *
     */
    namespace Webkul\Hello\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;




    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

            $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
            $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
            // here i am using item's product final price
            $price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()+10; // 10 is custom price. It will increase in product price.
            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

> app\code\Webkul\Hello\etc\frontend\checkout_cart_product_add_after.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="customprice" instance="Webkul\Hello\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: In which version of Magento 2.2? Have you try with static price for once?

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar sorry, I was my mistake. I am using magento 2.1.9

Comment: Try to remove return $this; Your code is working for me in magento 2.1.6. I am not using return statement.

Comment: Also need to confirm that are you using only simple product right ?

Comment: Magento doesn't recommends to use Observers for data modification, try using Plugins for data(input, output or both) modifications.

Comment: Anshu Misha is there any kind of documentation of not recommending `Observers for data modification`? I want to know that

Comment: @AmitBera https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html#14-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in your event file name,

Hoping that you didn't edit while asking question above,

The file name should be **events.xml** instead of **checkout_cart_product_add_after.xml**

Hope this helps :)